# Volley loads data only after clicking the button two times in recyclerview JSON

Tags: android, json, android-volley

I have an activity with several buttons . Each button loads a json data to the recyclerview from a json link.The problem with Volley here is
1) It loads the JSON data in the recyclerview only after I click the button two times (CLICK , GO BACK AND THEN CLICK). 
2) When I try to load the JSON data for other buttons , my data gets replicated and the list is not cleared.
3) If I manually clear the list using **json_list.clear()** then I get an empty recycler view.

This is my code...

```
public class PreviousQuestionPapers2 extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView firstYear;
    TextView secondYear;
    TextView thirdYear;
    TextView fourthYear;
    PopulateListsForClasses p1=new PopulateListsForClasses();
    Parcelable parcelable;
    List<SingleItemDetails> listToSend;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.prev_question_papers_second_dashboard);

        firstYear=findViewById(R.id.FIRST_YEAR);
        secondYear=findViewById(R.id.SECOND_YEAR);
        thirdYear=findViewById(R.id.THIRD_YEAR);
        fourthYear=findViewById(R.id.FOURTH_YEAR);

        listToSend=new ArrayList<SingleItemDetails>();

        final String branch = getIntent().getStringExtra("branch");

        firstYear.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                switch (branch)
                {
                    case "it":
                        populate_it_first_year();
                        listToSend = getList_to_return();
                        moveToNextActivity();
                        break;
                    case "cse":
                        populate_cse_first_year();
                        listToSend = getList_to_return();
                        moveToNextActivity();
                        break;
                    default:
                        Toast.makeText(PreviousQuestionPapers2.this,"UNDEFINED!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
secondYear.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                switch (branch)
                {
                    case "it":
                        populate_it_second_year();
                        listToSend =getList_to_return();
                        moveToNextActivity();
                        break;
                    case "cse":
                        populate_cse_second_year();
                        listToSend = getList_to_return();
                        moveToNextActivity();
                        break;
                default:                     Toast.makeText(PreviousQuestionPapers2.this,"UNDEFINED!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
List<SingleItemDetails>json_list=new ArrayList<>();

    String myurl;
    public List<SingleItemDetails> getList_to_return()
    {
        return json_list;
    }


    public void FetchJSONData(String url) {

        String JSON_URL = url;
        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.GET, JSON_URL, null, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                    try {
                        //JSONObject songObject = response.getJSONObject(i);
                        JSONObject movieObject = response.getJSONObject(i);

                        SingleItemDetails mov = new SingleItemDetails();
                        mov.setTitle(movieObject.getString("title"));
                        mov.setUrlForDownload(movieObject.getString("urlForDownload"));
                        json_list.add(mov);

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }

        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Log.d("tag", "onErrorResponse: " + error.getMessage());
            }
        });


        queue.add(jsonArrayRequest);

    }

        public void moveToNextActivity()
        {
            parcelable = Parcels.wrap(listToSend);
            Intent intent = new Intent(PreviousQuestionPapers2.this, RecyclerMainActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("listToDisplay", parcelable);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
        public void populate_it_first_year()
        {
            myurl = "http://www.json-generator.com/api/json/get/bUcmgeeCJK?indent=2";
            FetchJSONData(myurl);
        }
        public void populate_it_second_year() {
            myurl ="http://www.json-generator.com/api/json/get/bOOxdXLLWW?indent=2";
            FetchJSONData(myurl);
        }
        public void populate_cse_first_year () {
        myurl ="http://www.json-generator.com/api/json/get/ckWYWzcqrm?indent=2";
       }
       public void populate_cse_second_year () {
        myurl ="http://www.json-generator.com/api/json/get/clAEQTAhQi?indent=2";
       }
```

Comment: Volley requests are asynchronous. Your code moves you on to the next Activity as soon as the request is sent, not when the response is received.

Comment: Make your `RequestQueue` an instance variable of `PreviousQuestionPapers2` so that the request and listeners don't fall out of scope, and move your call to `moveToNextActivity` to the bottom of your positive response listener.